# Widget test - The "notifyListeners()" method of the mocked provider class is not rebuilding the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Consumer did not rebuild the widget when the "notifyListeners()" method of the mocked provider class called.
So basically, I'm trying to validate the textField. If the entered text characters are greater than 3, then enable the button and onChanged callback function of textField where the provider is rebuilding the widget every time text is entered, but mocked provider class is not rebuilding the widget.

Here is the test file -

```
class MockTextFProvider extends Mock implements TextFProvider {}

void main() {
 late MockTextFProvider mockTextFProvider;

 setUp(() {
   mockTextFProvider = MockTextFProvider();
 });

 Future<void> pumpScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
   return await tester.pumpWidget(
     MultiProvider(
       providers: [
         ChangeNotifierProvider<TextFProvider>.value(
           value: mockTextFProvider,
         ),
       ],
       child: const MaterialApp(
         home: TextFormF(),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 testWidgets('TextFormF empty value validation test',
     (WidgetTester tester) async {
   when(() => mockTextFProvider.notifyListeners()).thenAnswer((_) {});

   await pumpScreen(tester);

   // Find the TextFormField widget
   final textFieldFinder = find.byType(TextFormField);
   final bt = find.byType(ElevatedButton);

   expect(textFieldFinder, findsOneWidget);
   expect(bt, findsOneWidget);

   expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(bt).onPressed, null);

   await tester.enterText(textFieldFinder, 'Test Value of textfield');
   await tester.pump();
  
   expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(bt).onPressed, isNotNull);
 });
}
```

Screen which using Consumer -

```
class TextFormF extends StatefulWidget {
 const TextFormF({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<TextFormF> createState() => _TextFormFState();
}

class _TextFormFState extends State<TextFormF> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 String data = '';

 bool validate() {
   if (data.characters.length > 3) {
     return true;
   }

   return false;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(),
     body: Consumer<TextFProvider>(builder: (context, provider, _) {
       return Form(
         key: _formKey,
         child: Column(
           children: [
             TextFormField(
               validator: (String? value) {
                 if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
                   return "Empty value";
                 }
                 return null;
               },
               onChanged: (value) {
                 data = value!;
                 validate();

                 Provider.of<TextFProvider>(context, listen: false).notify();
               },
             ),
             ElevatedButton(
               onPressed: validate()
                   ? () {
                       if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                         ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                           const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                         );
                       }
                     }
                   : null,
               child: const Text('Validate'),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }),
   );
 }
}
```

Provider class -

```
class TextFProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
 void notify(){
   notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand when and why you need mocks, because in this situation you absolutely DO NOT need a mock of `TextFProvider`.

TLDR: just remove the mock of `TextFProvider` - `MockTextFProvider`, and replace it with an instance of `TextFProvider`. That's it:

```
void main() {
  Future<void> pumpScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
    return await tester.pumpWidget(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<TextFProvider>(
            create: (context) => TextFProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: const MaterialApp(
          home: TextFormF(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  testWidgets('TextFormF empty value validation test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await pumpScreen(tester);

    // Find the TextFormField widget
    final textFieldFinder = find.byType(TextFormField);
    final bt = find.byType(ElevatedButton);

    expect(textFieldFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(bt, findsOneWidget);

    expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(bt).onPressed, null);

    await tester.enterText(textFieldFinder, 'Test Value of textfield');
    await tester.pump();

    expect(tester.widget<ElevatedButton>(bt).onPressed, isNotNull);
  });
}
```

Reason why your test fails: UI just does not get repainted.
Why? Because you mocked the object(`TextFProvider`) and its method(`notifyListeners()`), which are responsible for repainting:

```
when(() => mockTextFProvider.notifyListeners()).thenAnswer((_) {});
```

P.S. There are some things, that can be done using better practices, but that's out of topic.